# PHP while loop to read multiline text from string

Tags: php, string, while-loop, multiline

I have a multiline string and that have 2 words in line.
I want within a while loop while reading the script line by line
get the 1st word and 2nd word.

```
$multilinestring="name1  5
name2 8
name3 34
name5 55 ";
```

The result i want to have while i am reading the the string line by line is to get 
2 more strings

`$firstword` and `$secondword`

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really a text file you want to read, then you'd be better of to use `fgets()` or read the file to an array completely with `file()` and use `explode()` afterwards. Consider this code:

```
$arr = file("somefile.txt"); // read the file to an array
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++) { // loop over it
    $tmp = explode(" ", $arr[$i]); // splits the string, returns an array
    $firstword = $tmp[0];
    $secondword = $tmp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$eachLine = explode(PHP_EOL, $multilinestring); // best practice is to explode using EOL (End Of Line).
foreach ($eachLine as $line) { 
  $line = explode(" ", $line);
  $firstword = $line[0];
  $secondword = $line[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the point in using a while loop to do this? Use foreach loop to achieve this:

```
foreach (explode("\n", $multilinestring) as $line) { 
  $line = explode(" ", $line);
  print_r($line);
}
```